# unrecognized property "cflags" for cc_prebuilt_library_shared module

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries, android-source, android-build

I am writing `Android.bp` file for one of the prebuild library. In `Android.mk` It was possible to add CFlags for prebuilt library; however same is not working in case of blueprint i.e. `Android.bp`. A snippet of what I am doing is below:

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "samplelib",
    vendor_available:true,
    cflags: [
       "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Werror",
    ],
    tags: [
        "optional",
        "eng",
        "debug",
    ],

    target: {
        android_x86:{
                 srcs: ["bin/x86/samplelib.so"],
                 compile_multilib: "32",
                 relative_install_path: "lib",
        },
        android_x86_64:{
                 srcs: ["bin/x86_64/samplelib.so"],
                 compile_multilib: "64",
                 relative_install_path: "lib64",
        },
   },
}
```

However I am getting following error:

```
/Android.bp:5:11: unrecognized property "cflags"
```

So if I understand correctly, `cflags` can't be used with `cc_prebuilt_library_shared` module; if that's the case how can we enable `CFlags` for this module then ?

Comment: Try putting them in a `cc_defaults {}` block.

Comment: @rekire Tried already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not sounding relevant; but the fix was setting `LOCAL_STRIP_MODULE` to None and removing `cflags` from the `Android.bp` file. So working snippet looks like this:

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "samplelib",
    vendor_available:true,
    tags: [
        "optional",
        "eng",
        "debug",
    ],

    target: {
        android_x86:{
                 srcs: ["bin/x86/samplelib.so"],
                 compile_multilib: "32",
                 relative_install_path: "lib",
        },
        android_x86_64:{
                 srcs: ["bin/x86_64/samplelib.so"],
                 compile_multilib: "64",
                 relative_install_path: "lib64",
        },
   },
    strip: {
            none:true,
    },
}
```

Notice `"strip"` attribute which is set to none and `cflags` is also removed.

**Note: `"strip"` attribute is blueprint version of `LOCAL_STRIP_MODULE` of makefile.**

Answer (score 1):

Having `cflags` for prebuilt binaries does not make much sense. They are provided to the compiler when building C/C++ files. Since your libraries are already built you should not need them.

Comment: Agree! Got to know about that later; but even after removing them; It ain't working.  I have posted solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754629/1944896